# Having trouble integrating Twilio SMS Messaging into my web app

Tags: vb.net, twilio, twilio-api

I am looking to incorporate a simple, one-way SMS Messaging solution into my web app. Despite years of experience using ASP.NET/VB.NET/Javascript for my web development, the SDK's and the API's I'm looking at on Twilio's site are clearly over my head.
My web app is a not-yet-launched application to manage appointments for a variety of industries.
My needs:
Customer makes an appointment, the vendor gets a text containing the details.
The vendor confirms the appointment, the customer receives a confirmation.
That's it and that simple!!! That's all I need. No additional responses, or analytics, or monitoring etc. are required.
I look at the Twilio documentation and I have no idea where to even begin and, as much as I'd love to learn it all, I don't have the opportunity to devote the time to it... at least not at the present time.
So, what do I need to simply have an SMS txet message sent when my "Thank You" page loads after an appointment request is made? I will be capturing form data from the page to "craft" the actual message thatb gets sent but that will be about as involved as it will get and that is something I can handle on my end.
Any help, utilizing a VB.NET solution, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read this: (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-a-message-with-an-image-url&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json), this is "the basics", a POST request to Twilio's API. All the other libs are just sugar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are looking at how to get started sending an SMS message with VB.NET then this tutorial is where you should begin: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-vbnet

It shows how to use the [Twilio .NET helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp) to send messages with VB.NET, including all the steps for signing up, getting a number and sending the message.

The example code is here:

```
Imports Twilio
Imports Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account
Imports Twilio.Types

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        Const  accountSid = "your_account_sid"
        Const  authToken = "your_auth_token"
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken)

        Dim toNumber = New PhoneNumber("+15017250604")
        Dim message = MessageResource.Create(
            toNumber, from := New PhoneNumber("+15558675309"), 
            body := "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?")

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am already signed up with a phone number with Twilio. My problem is with installing the the C# / .NET helper library. This is something I've never done before. Where is the library? Where do I install it, local machine or server? How do I install it? I wish there was a step-by-step guide. Instead it makes the assumption that you are already familiar with installing/working with SDK's/API's.

Comment: There are instructions for installing the .NET helper library here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with installing a .NET SDK myself, so that's all I can help with.